# I was trying to create a stack data type using array in pointer. But my program is giving segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, stack

This is the code here. Even after debugging I'm not able to find the problem. The code was working fine if I'm not using the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack{
   int size;
   int top;
   int *arr;
```

};

```
int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr){
if ((*ptr).top == -1){
    return 1;
}
else{
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
 int main()
 {
struct stack *s;
(*s).size = 80;
(*s).top = -1;
(*s).arr = (int *)malloc((*s).size * sizeof(int));

// Check if stack is empty
if(isEmpty(s)){
    printf("The stack is empty");
}
else{
    printf("The stack is not empty");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct stack *s; (*s).size = 80`. Can't do that. `s` is an unintialized pointer. Dereferencing uninitialised pointers is Undefined Behaviour. Allocate memory with `malloc` or declare it as a `struct` rather than a pointer.

Comment: Use `->` instead of `.` and `*` when accessing a member of pointer to a struct. Your seg fault happens because you didn't intialize `s` with malloc / calloc.

Comment: in C, the returned type for `malloc()`, `calloc()`, and `realloc()` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  Suggest removing the cast.  OT: for robust code, always check the returned code (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call: `perror( "your error message" );` to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not allocate any memory for your struct. You may decalre it on the stack: `struct stack s;` or allocate memory for it: `struct stack *s = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));`.

When you have a pointer to a struct, please use the `->` operator to access its members like so `s->size`.